# cakePHP login, multiple controllers possible?

Tags: php, cakephp

hi im trying to grasp cake(been thrown in to the deep end, without much help and tutorials seem to be a little scarce)

My question is we have three different types of users - business, businessUser, individual, we have created a table,model and controller for each three of the users. Is it possible to create one login page when using three types of controllers or do we need to combine everything into one controller and go from there?

sorry for such a beginner question but at this point I'm getting kind of desperate.

business - has many businessusers btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your models need a bit of tweeking. I'd suggest the following schema:

```
users table (User model)
- Contains information shared by all user types (name, password, etc.)

business table (Business model)
- Contains information unique to a business

business_users (BusinessUser)
- Contains information unique to a business user

individuals (Individual)
- Contains information unique to an individual (can this be combined with the User model?)
```

Now, you can link them up like this:

```
User hasOne Business
User hasOne BusinessUser
User hasOne Individual

Business belongsTo User
BusinessUser belongsTo User
Individual belongsToUse
```

A business would be defined as a User with an associate Business model, etc.

Comment: you beauty this is exactly what i was looking for! thanks mate!

Comment: one question though, would all the functions like adduser and validation be in the user model?

Answer (score 0):

You **could** create three separate logins, if they are three completely different systems that will never share data or need to interact.

But it would probably be  a better idea to rework your thinking.

`User hasMany UserGroups`.

`UserGroup` - `id`, `role` (e.g. BusinessUser, Individual). This approach allows you to extend should you ever need to without creating new controllers for different roles. It does depend really on what you are trying to achieve with these "user groups".

Handle the login in your `user` controller, and then depending on the user group, control access accordingly.

Or even just give the `user` a `role`, and again, depending on role, control access.

The cookbook offers a [similar example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

Comment: unfortunately they all need to be able to interact with each other, the program is similar to a banking system.